# New style for part of super user

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The logo for Super user, I interpret as a `[` square bracket and a `}` curly bracket, with a `·` middle dot in between. [·}.

[image]

To keep that style, I noticed a place it could be added. When there is a new question, you get a little (1) in the tab.

[image]

I thought that instead of (1), it could be {1} or [1}. I don't know if this would look good (especially for larger numbers, like {117} or [117} but I thought it might be nice.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's a funny suggestion, but I'm fairly sure there's not a lot of gain from it, also considering the time needed to implement it as a special case for one site only.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would probably be annoying, and ruin the identical programming...

Comment: I have wished for many minor changes in Stack Exchange over the years, but this one seriously takes the cake.

Comment: My OCD is tingling with this request :-)

Comment: I wonder if its userscriptable.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yep. And pretty simple. Heck, I'll do one if someone asks.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Please, do contact Jin about this and see what the SE designer thinks about it!

Comment: Well status declined so I guess no!

Comment: @Tim The SE team can override moderator decisions of question statuses, so I think you should still contact Jin. When a moderator adds a status tag, he's just predicting what the SE team will say, but the SE team can always override that mod decision if they want.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Who is jin?

Comment: @Tim http://stackexchange.com/about, search for "Jin Yang"